# How do we sneak into Beta App releases?

Tags: discussion

It's phwd here again for a next attempt at taking this site beyond [hit-and-run](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/913/is-this-site-not-running-as-well-as-it-deserves/914#914).

My question of the day is: how do we get early invites to products released as apps? I think this would be a good way to at least build sub-communities around these apps. These companies can use WebApps as *one* way of dealing with support and commonly asked questions.

A recent example that is working, so far, is that of Trello.

Are there any places that we should be looking at to monitor who is coming out with the next big thing *and* how to get early access to understanding how to use their app?

Answer (score 4):

Getting in there *before* the site decides to use us as a support channel would be a "good thing" <sup>tm</sup> so we can avoid the problems that Trello highlighted.

It would also be a positive act.

Answer (score 3):

TechCrunch, Lifehacker and Mashable appear to be the go to places you want to learn about new and upcoming web apps.

What we need to do is make it so that the web apps set to launch send the beta invites and pre-release account invites toward Web Apps first/same day as the outlets.

Better promotion of what the site can offer to the promotions arms, as a place people can also refer to for help (but not as its primary and sole means) and how the organic word of mouth and questions/answers can, if done right, be beneficial for both parties.

Comment: [hacker news](http://news.ycombinator.com/) too